# Timecode Burn-In from Source TC

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a TC Burn-In that correctly displays the source video's TC.

My current FFMPEG filter line is:

`-filter_complex "[0:1][0:2] amerge" -preset ultrafast -vf scale=960:540:in_range=tv:out_range=pc,"drawtext=\timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':timecode_rate=25:x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh):fontcolor=white@1:fontsize=30:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.6" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 27 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -b:a 128k`

This of course starts the Burn-In at 00:00:00:00, but I'd rather insert the file's TC (in this case, it starts at 10:00:00:00) -- data taken from MediaInfo:

```
Other #1
ID                                       : 1-Material
Type                                     : Time code
Format                                   : MXF TC
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Time code of first frame                 : 10:00:00:00
Time code of last frame                  : 10:02:34:20
Time code settings                       : Material Package
Time code, stripped                      : Yes
Title                                    : Timecode

Other #2
ID                                       : 0-Source
Type                                     : Time code
Format                                   : MXF TC
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Time code of first frame                 : 10:00:00:00
Time code of last frame                  : 10:02:34:20
Time code settings                       : Source Package
Time code, stripped                      : Yes

Other #3
Type                                     : Time code
Format                                   : SMPTE TC
Muxing mode                              : SDTI
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Time code of first frame                 : 10:00:00:00
```

I have not found a way to make FFMPEG read the TC and use it for the Burn-In. Do any of you guys know how to accomplish this?

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ever has the same issue: ffmpeg by itself is not able to read the file's TC and use it to burn in TC (as of January 2023).

There is a workflow tool for encoding that I use (FFAStrans -- it's free and it's awesome) that can achieve this: https://ffastrans.com/frm/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1442

Answer (score 0):

It is makeable.
You can get the timecode value with ffprobe and then inject that string into drawtext's `timecode='00\:00\:00\:00'`.

I put together a small shell script for this:

```bash
INPUT=myinputfile.mp4

OUTPUT=myoutputfile.mp4

# Parse Start TC of data stream with ffprobe:
# > video stream (v) also has a timecode tag, is it always the same?
TC=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams d -show_entries stream_tags=timecode -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $INPUT)
if [[$TC = ""]]; then
TC="00:00:00:00"
fi
echo "TC: "$TC

# Parse Frame Rate of video stream with ffprobe:
FPS=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $INPUT)
if [[$FPS = ""]]; then
FPS="25/1"
fi
echo "FPS: "$FPS

# String replacement:
TCR=${TC//:/\\:}
echo $TCR

DRAW="fontfile=/Library/Fonts/DroidSansMono.ttf:timecode='$TCR':rate=$FPS:text='TC_':fontsize=60:fontcolor=white@0.8:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=10:box=1:x=W/2-tw/2:y=H-(H*0.12)"
echo $DRAW

# Finished command:
ffmpeg -i $INPUT -vf drawtext=$DRAW -y $OUTPUT
```

Unfortunately there's all the usual shell string escape hocuspokus.